# Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{\frac{2}{1+2i\pi f}-\frac{2}{4+2i\pi f}}{\frac{1}{1+2i\pi f}+\frac{1}{3+2i\pi f}}$

Tags: filters, fourier-transform, continuous-signals

I wanted to calculated the inverse fourier transform of the transfer function :
\begin{align}
H(f) &= \frac{\frac{2}{1+2i\pi f}-\frac{2}{4+2i\pi f}}{\frac{1}{1+2i\pi f}+\frac{1}{3+2i\pi f}}\\
&\text{
I did some simplification : 
}\\
&= \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2+i\pi f}+\frac{1}{1+i\pi f}\right)
\end{align}

and after applying $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{H(f)\}$ I obtained

$$ h(t)=\frac{3}{2}\left(e^{-4t}+e^{-2t}\right)u(t)$$ $$(this\ formula\ is\ corrected)$$

I used the fact that $$\mathcal{F}\left\{e^{-at} u(t)\right\}= \frac{1}{a+2i\pi f}$$

where $ u(t)$ is the unit step function.

Can I get some help to know if my process is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks correct; obviously you need to simplify to obtain a transfer function with polynomials as numerator and denominator. Partial fraction expansion then leads to a form that can be directly transformed to the time domain. The only thing that might be wrong is the minus sign between the two exponentials.

Comment: much appreciated for your help and for the editing. you are right it should be a plus sign between the exponentials